# what will be returned in this function

Tags: php, function, return

I have a pretty basic question about returning a value out of a function:
I know that for instance in the function below, a string is what will return:

```
function sample_1() {
return 'STRING';
}
```

or in this one, what ever the variable would be:

```
function sample_2($var) {
return $var;
}
```

but what if nothing mentioned as the value for returning. In other words, what is the value returned in this one:

```
class Sample_3{
function __set($var, $value) {
    if ('STRING' == $var) {
        $this->$var = $value;
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For sample_3 to work, it should be encased in a class. In any case, the returned value would be [NULL](http://codepad.org/hFYKeNha).

Comment: It will return `null` but what do you want to be returned?

Comment: Yes! Sample_3 is a class. So if it returns NULL, what's the point? Does it change if I remove return part?

Comment: For setter functions, you don't need a return. Only use it if you want to jump out, such as `if ($value == 'bad_value') return;` so that it doesn't do anything. Of course, you could always reverse the logic and state `if ($value != 'bad_value') $this->$var = $value;`. It's all up to you.

Comment: There is no point in the return statement in Sample_3 - UNLESS another statement follows the if check. the return would trigger a leaving of the function at that position - all code after that is ignored - it's called "early exit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the return is omitted the value NULL will be returned.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Return used as "early exit":

```
class Sample_3{
function __set($var, $value) {
    if ('STRING' == $var) {
        $this->$var = $value;
        return; // if this point is reached, exit __set
    }
    // code not processed, if var is STRING
    if ('ANOTHER-STRING' == $var) {
        $this->$var = $value;
        return;
    }
}
}
```